# Correctly setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH after installing a module with easy_install

Tags: python, native, easy-install

I have installed the `pyodbc` Python module by running `easy_install path/to/egg`. The module uses native code. The output indicated success.

However when trying to `import pyodbc`, an error is raised: `cannot open shared object file`.

Research on this site shows that Python looks for native libraries in the path specified by the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. So I should set it to point to the path where `easy_install` has put the native files during installation.

However, I can't find this path. I have looked in `/usr/lib`, `/usr/lib64`, and some more directories which made sense (I'm not currently on the Linux machine at work, so I'm sorry I can't remember the additional directories I looked in).

Please explain where this can path be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://zxtech.wordpress.com/tag/pyodbc/):

you must set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` (in your .profile or .bashrc or .zshrc) which points to where the `unixodbc` and `freetds` shared libraries got installed if you installed them via your system's package manager.

i.e. if you are on ubuntu, type `apt-get install freedts unixodbc`

pyodbc is just a wrapper around the C library, hence this requirements.

One last but important thing, after setting your LD_LIBRARY_PATH in one of these environment files, do either colose and reopen your terminal's shell or for example `source ~/.bashrc` (if you had put this in your bashrc obviously)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have looked in `/usr/local/lib`, and this library is empty. Does this mean `easy_install` put the files elsewhere?

Comment: if you are on ubuntu, type apt-get install freedts unixodbc

Comment: You mean I need to install the ODBC driver? I did from the RPM. Or do you mean there is an additional installation I need to do?

Comment: Will `pyodbc` not work if `freedts` and `unixodbc` have not been installed seperately?

Comment: Because, as I mentioned above, pyodbc if just a c-wrapper around the unix package unixodbc. without it, it cannot work.

Comment: I see. I understand I need unixodbc. But do I need freedts if I have installed the suitable ODBC driver?